# NoClassDefFoundError for com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a written a small program which runs correctly in eclipse, but when I created a jar and trying to run the same code, I am getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE`
Please suggest.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the Jar file `sunjce_provider.jar` is in you classpath. Normally it is in directory `$JAVA_HOME/lib/ext`.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure:

- you are using Oracle's Java SE when you run the jar. Other JVMs does not have this provider by default.
- you have installed the java unlimited jurisdiction policy files on the **JVM running the jar**

Note that you may check the available providers and algorithms with the following code:

```
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
      Provider p[] = Security.getProviders();
      for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
          System.out.println(p[i]);
          for (Enumeration e = p[i].keys(); e.hasMoreElements();)
              System.out.println("\t" + e.nextElement());
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

found [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/ListAllProviderAndItsAlgorithms.htm).

Comment: In OpenJDK it's also included `http://grepcode.com/search/?r=repository.grepcode.com$java$root&start=0&query=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE&entity=type`

Comment: Can you please add some more light on this issue?